# Manipulating a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a dataset (satellite data) - Here is the link:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qBOROSDHSRMykZjWgP7iRMtpQ3gBMceL?usp=sharing

To read a specific part of the dataset one uses:

```
LISTA = FileNames[]; (* Here you assume you have your files in one specific Directory and list them*)

data1 = Import[
   LISTA[[1]], {"Datasets", "/PRODUCT/methane_mixing_ratio"}];
```

Checking the data structure one gets

```
Dimensions[data1]
```

> {1, 4173, 215}

I want to get rid of some of the background (or NaN data) and put 0 (zeroes)

```
Newdata1 = Flatten[ReplaceAll[data1, s_ /; s > 5000 -> 0]]
```

When this is done however the data structure is "destroyed" and becomes only large one element list

```
Dimensions[Newdata1]
```

> {897195}

**Is there a way to replace those number and keep its structure (1 x 4173 x 214) ?**

I have tried doing it without using the Flatten option but then I does not work I have seen some of the questions here and this might be a case of nested list issue, but I am not sure how to solve that .

Comment: You can use `Replace` to specify the level where you want to do the replacements. E.g., `Replace[RandomReal[1, {3, 4, 5}], s_ /; s > 0.5 :> -1, {3}]`

Comment: Alternatively, also have a look at `Select` and `Cases`.

Comment: @Natas `Select` and `Cases` will most certainly destroy the structure of the data.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit I guess it would be a bit cumbersome to keep the structure with those. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Yes, I was having a hard time to figure out the level. thanks

Comment: It looks like the reason you lost the structure is because of the Flatten command in Newdata1, not because of the substitution.

Answer (score 1):

A case for `Clip`?

```
Clip[RandomReal[10000, {3, 4, 5}],{5000,Infinity},{0,Infinity}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`Threshold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Threshold.html), which, to my surprise, is faster than `Clip`.

```
SeedRandom[1]
data1 = RandomReal[10000, {1, 4173, 215}];
```

**Replacing numbers greater than 5000 with 0:**

```
t1a = First @ RepeatedTiming[
    res1a = Subtract[data1, Threshold[data1, 5000 + $MachineEpsilon]]];
t2a = First @ RepeatedTiming[res2a = Clip[data1, {0, 5000}, {0, 0}]];
t3a = First @ RepeatedTiming[res3a = data1 UnitStep[Subtract[5000, data1]]];
t4a = First @ RepeatedTiming[res4a = Replace[data1, s_ /; s > 5000 -> 0., All]];
t5a = First @ RepeatedTiming[res5a = ReplaceAll[data1, s_ /; s > 5000 -> 0.]];

res1a == res2a == res3a == res4a == res5a
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
Dimensions @ res1a
```

> ```
>  {1, 4173, 215}
> ```

**Replacing numbers less than 5000 with 0:**

```
t1b = First @ RepeatedTiming[res1b = Threshold[data1, 5000 + $MachineEpsilon]];
t2b = First @ RepeatedTiming[res2b = Clip[data1, {5000, ∞}, {0, ∞}]];
t3b = First @ RepeatedTiming[res3b = data1 UnitStep[Subtract[data1, 5000]]];
t4b = First @ RepeatedTiming[res4b = Replace[data1, s_ /; s < 5000 -> 0., All]];
t5b = First @ RepeatedTiming[res5b = ReplaceAll[data1, s_ /; s < 5000 -> 0.]];

res1b == res2b == res3b == res4b == res5b
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
Dimensions @ res1b
```

> ```
>  {1, 4173, 215}
> ```

**Timing comparisons**

```
{timingsa, timingsb} = {{t1a, t2a, t3a, t4a, t5a}, {t1b, t2b, t3b, t4b, t5b}};

functionsa = {"Subtract[data1,Threshold[data1,5000+$MachineEpsilon]]",
    "Clip[data1,{0,5000},{0,0}]", 
   "data1 UnitStep[Subtract[5000,data1]]", 
   "Replace[data1,s_/;s>5000\[Rule]0., All]", 
   "ReplaceAll[data1,s_/;s>5000\[Rule]0.]"};

functionsb = {"Threshold[data1,5000+$MachineEpsilon]", 
   "Clip[data1,{5000, Infinity},{0,Infinity}]", 
   "data1 UnitStep[Subtract[data1,5000]]", 
   "Replace[data1,s_/;s<5000\[Rule]0., All]", 
   "ReplaceAll[data1,s_/;s<5000\[Rule]0.]"};

Grid[Join[{{Item["Replace numbers greater than 5000 with 0", 
     Background -> LightBlue], SpanFromLeft}}, 
  Transpose[{functionsa, timingsa}], 
 {{Item["Replace numbers less than 5000 with 0", 
     Background -> LightBlue], SpanFromLeft}}, 
  Transpose[{functionsb, timingsb}]], 
 Alignment -> {{Left, "."}, Center}, Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow. Good to know Threshold!